# npm install --save loopback-connector-mongodb failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, loopbackjs, node-gyp

Im a newbie in node.js and I want to learn loopback. I tried to follow this tutorial and first part went well, until I got to install loopback connector to mongodb.

```
npm install --save loopback-connector-mongodb
```

I got error which seems to be really hard to find on web and I have really poor knowledge of npm and node-gyp and mongodb so I dont know even understand whats wrong. Could anyone suggest how to fix it?

This is terminal log:

```
npm WARN package.json loopback-getting-started@1.0.0 No license field.
-
> kerberos@0.0.14 install /home/qw/Work/Nodejs-Apps/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/home/qw/Work/Nodejs-Apps/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
../lib/kerberosgss.c:27:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic push
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c:28:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
 ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: In function ‘authenticate_gss_client_wrap’:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:348:19: warning: variable ‘server_conf_flags’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   char buf[4096], server_conf_flags;
                   ^
../lib/kerberosgss.c: At top level:
../lib/kerberosgss.c:687:0: warning: ignoring #pragma clang diagnostic [-Wunknown-pragmas]
 #pragma clang diagnostic pop
 ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos.node
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi_krb5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
kerberos.target.mk:133: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/kerberos.node' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/kerberos.node] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/qw/Work/Nodejs-Apps/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-26-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/qw/Work/Nodejs-Apps/loopback-getting-started/node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
loopback-connector-mongodb@1.13.0 node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb
├── async@1.4.2
├── loopback-connector@2.3.0
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
└── mongodb@2.0.43 (es6-promise@2.1.1, readable-stream@1.0.31, mongodb-core@1.2.12)
```

I have node version 4.0.0, ubuntu mate 15.04 and mongo 3.0.6

Comment: Do you have gcc or build-essential package? See https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp for node-gyp requirements.

Comment: Yes I do. I have installed node.gyp succesfully I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lkrb5` says it couldn't find the library `libkrb5` required to build kerberos module. Just install that library: `apt-get install libkrb5-dev` to get rid of that error message. See [installation guide](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/79a59e39dbdbfbe40d64e4d268611baf481d0ec1/docs/reference/content/getting-started/installation-guide.md#troubleshooting).

But mongodb driver would run fine without it, only kerberos authentication won't be supported.